# Wordpress plugin install asking for FTP Information

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ftp

Good day,
I'm trying to install plugins in a new wp theme but it always asks for FTP 
Information. After reading different blogs, this is what i have done:

1. I added `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in `wp-config.php` file
2. I set the permission of the project folder and all inclosed folders to read and write

But all the above failed to solve my problem.

I'm working on a Mac, with Sierra as operating system and I'm using Xampp.
Check the attached picture.
Kindly help

Regards

[image: the control panel]

Comment: Were did you add FS_MEHOD ?

Comment: right under define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is add the following FTP information to your `wp-config.php`

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FTP_BASE', '/usr/home/username/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/home/username/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/usr/home/username/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
```

Comment: Thanks @purvik7373 . It worked for most plugins, but there is this plugin called Envato Wordpress Toolkit, i can successfully install it but i can't activate it (no activate button even after page refresh)

Comment: @Reagan Did you mean the only "Envato Wordpress Toolkit" plugin create a problem right?

Comment: Yes, only that plugin ! @purvik7373

Comment: @Reagan Would you please enable `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` and check error?

Comment: i did it and now i can't even login into the dashboard. check how it looks now [link] http://prntscr.com/dz6yc3

Comment: @Reagan It's might be issue with `masterslider plugin`. Would you please bkp your `masterslider folder` in your plugin directory. and check it?

Comment: Yes you're right @purvik7373 . Thanks for saving my day. Imma list this as helpful

Comment: @Reagan If this answer would be helpful to you then please mark it as approved so it could be helpful for others :)